# Download GeoJSON-Map from ArcGis-Server

Tags: rest, geojson, arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm trying to download a map of all roads in the German state of North Rhine Westphalia in the GeoJSON-format. I found an ArcGIS-hosted server using a REST-Api and tried to understand how it works but as I am completely new to using these services, I might have made a mistake somewhere. Maybe anyone can help me...

I just added f=geojson to the REST-URL but then nothing happens although the GeoJSON-format should be supported. Where did I make a mistake?

The address is: https://www.arcgishostedserver.nrw.de/arcgis/rest/services/Verkehrswege_NRW/MapServer/0/

So in my case I tried https://www.arcgishostedserver.nrw.de/arcgis/rest/services/Verkehrswege_NRW/MapServer/0/f=geojson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you mentioned is meant to provide general information about a single layer (id=0) in a Map Service.

To get the actual data, you need to use the Query operation. You can see a link to the supported operations in the end of the HTML page of the layer (first URL in your question), and you can also add the `f=geojson` parameter to get it in GeoJson format. Note that you must provide at least `where` parameter to specify the quety.

For example, this will fetch all features where OBJECTID field is lower than 10, as GeoJson:

https://www.arcgishostedserver.nrw.de/arcgis/rest/services/Verkehrswege_NRW/MapServer/0/query?where=OBJECTID+%3C+10&f=geojson

If you set `f=html` (or just omit `f`), you'll get an HTML form for setting all optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am new too but just change f value. It works

2 Layers:

Strassennetz_Stand20190731_Dis (0)

```
https://www.arcgishostedserver.nrw.de/arcgis/rest/services/Verkehrswege_NRW/MapServer/0/?f=pjson
```

Bahnstrecken_Stand012019 (1)

```
https://www.arcgishostedserver.nrw.de/arcgis/rest/services/Verkehrswege_NRW/MapServer/1/?f=pjson
```

Comment: This will not fetch the actual features of the layer, only some general metadata.